# Parsing Wikipedia .bz2 dump

Tags: mediawiki, data-mining, wiki

I have downloaded the compressed Wikipedia corpus in .bz2 form. Is there a way to search through that bulk of data for a keyword without having to use an API? I need to upload the whole database on a server and search through it for data mining purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, `bzcat`/`bzgrep` is the closest thing to "not using an API".

But at some point, you will want to think about search APIs for *faster* searching.